# Having trouble indexing an int array with defined limits?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm seriously confused right now. I'm working on a school project that uses overloading. I have a constructor that has two parameters, a lower index and upper index for an int array. Here is the constructor:

```
IntArray::IntArray(int lower, int upper){
    arrLower = lower;
    arrUpper = upper;
    // Creates array size
    size = arrUpper - arrLower;
    operator[](size);
}
```

and when my program gets to this testing point via this function:

```
void test2() {
    cout << "2. Array declared with two integers: IntArray b(-3, 6);" << endl << endl;
    csis << "2. Array declared with two integers: IntArray b(-3, 6);" << endl << endl;
    IntArray b(-3, 6);
    //cout << b.low() << " " << b.high();
    for(int i = b.low(); i <= b.high(); i++)
         b[i] = i * 10;
    b.setName("b");
    cout << b << endl;
    csis << b << endl;
    wait();
}
```

it seizes and utilizes all of my cpu power. the `low()` and `high()` functions simply return `arrLower` and `arrUpper`. What I don't understand is why it works if I add

```
cout << b.low() << " " << b.high() << endl;
```

after the constructor call.

Why does adding a cout statement fix my problem? Am I not managing memory properly?

heres the full WIP program if you want to look at it. It's not done by a long shot.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/963fb80351ae23c58f18

Comment: Why are you declaring your main function in the header? There is no need to do that.

Comment: What do your `operator[]` look like? What does it do? Can it handle negative start indexes? And when you call it with `size`, aren't you technically using an index that is beyond the end of the upper bound?

Comment: `operator[](size);` doesn't do what you think it's doing.

Comment: `operator[](size);` This doesn't make any sense. If you want to allocate memory here, you ought to say `something = new int[size];`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Now that I think of it, the operator[] function probably is not working with the upper and lower definitions. I had it use an `int` value to define the `size` variable, but when I did that it would only define `size` from `0`.

Comment: You are going to have to save the lower limit so you can map it to the start of the array.  For example a lower of 2 and upper of 4 has 3 slots.  C++ will number the indices 0, 1, and 2.  Your clients will number the indices 2, 3, and 4.  Using indices of 3 and 4 in your program will cause a buffer overrun and undefined behavior or values.